# Accessing Data Between Storyboard Views 1 and 3

Tags: ios, view, storyboard

The scenario is I have a storyboard with view one connecting to view two via swipe. Then view two connecting to view three via swipe (they all go back and forth between one another with left and right swipes).

My problem is in accessing data between views one and three. View three holds a textbox whose value I want to show on a label on view one. How?

I've read that the best way to do so is through the use of segues, but it seems the `prepareSegue()` allows data to be added and subsequently moved to the adjacent view (i.e. view three to view two). Am I wrong in this interpretation? Is there a easy way to access the data between non-joint views?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at using a singleton class to store the data. The singleton would be accessed in views 1 & 3 and view 2 doesn't have to know about it.

Comment: Great solution! I was headed down the way of using a shared class, but didn't have the exact implementation details for Objective-C. I was able to get things going now with this solution. To me, its obviously a mirror approach to using the built-in default preferences, but with a bit more wiggle room.